# How to close correctly the virustotal uploader tool after uploading a file by batch?

Tags: batch-file, file-upload

I'm making a batch file to download the virustotal uploader tool in order to upload a suspect file.
The problem is after being uploaded by this tool, it remain opened !

So, my question is : **How to close correctly the virustotal uploader tool after uploading a file by batch ?**

[image]

```dos
@echo off
Mode con cols=80 lines=3 & color 9E
Title VirusTotal Uploader by Hackoo 2017
::*********************************************************************************
:Main
Set "File2Upload=%windir%\system32\wscript.exe"
echo(
echo     Please wait a while ! Uploading file to VirusTotal is in progress ...
Set "VirusTotalUploaderTool=%ProgramFiles%\VirusTotalUploader2\VirusTotalUploader2.2.exe"
If Not Exist "%VirusTotalUploaderTool%" (
    Call:Downloading
) else (
    Start /wait "" "%VirusTotalUploaderTool%" "%File2Upload%"
)
Taskkill /IM "VirusTotalUploader2.2.exe" /F
exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Downloading
Title Downloading VirusTotal Uploader Tool v2.2 by Hackoo 2017
Mode con cols=80 lines=3 & color 9E
Set "URL=https://www.virustotal.com/static/bin/vtuploader2.2.exe"
Rem Create "MyDownload" folder in the temporary folder
set "MyDownload_Folder=%temp%\MyDownload"
If Not Exist "%MyDownload_Folder%" MD "%MyDownload_Folder%"
Set "Setup_File=%MyDownload_Folder%\vtuploader2.2.exe"
echo(
echo     Please wait a while ! downloading "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
Rem Downloading vtuploader2.2.exe to the temporary folder
Call :Download "%URL%" "%Setup_File%"
cls
Color 9A 
Title Installing "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
echo(
echo                 Installing "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
Rem Silent installation of vtuploader2.2.exe the uploading tool
Call :Install_Silently %Setup_File% 
Rem Removing the download folder
Call :Clean %MyDownload_Folder%
Goto Main
Exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Install_Silently <Setup_File>
"%~1" /S
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Clean <Folder_Setup>
RD "%~1" /S /Q >nul
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for your remark, you have reason, oupss !!! my bad i miss it and i corrected it ! because i'm focusing how can i be sure that the file is succssefully uploaded and close it by batch and **not manaually** as is shown in my new edit with image added !

Hope that you undestand what i mean now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answser my self and i share my code with you !

This is a special batch in order to upload all your ***.exe** suscpects files located on your temporary folder with command line to **VirusTotal.com** in the same time.

***Multi_VirusTotal_Uploader.bat***

```dos
@echo off
Color 9B & Mode con cols=90 lines=5
Title "%~nx0" for Multi-files VirusTotal Uploader by Hackoo 2017
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set TmpLogFile=%tmp%\TmpLog.txt
If Exist %TmpLogFile% Del %TmpLogFile%
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >%TmpLogFile% 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                      **************************************
ECHO                       Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                      **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Title "%~nx0" for Multi-files VirusTotal Uploader by Hackoo 2017
:Main
Mode con cols=90 lines=3 & color 9E
Set "VirusTotalUploaderTool=%ProgramFiles%\VirusTotalUploader2\VirusTotalUploader2.2.exe"
If Not Exist "%VirusTotalUploaderTool%" ( Call:Downloading )
Set "Files_List2Upload=%~dp0ListFiles.txt"
echo(
echo           Creating a list of all *.exe files located on your temporary folder ...
Timeout /t 4 /NoBreak>nul
Dir /b /s /A:-D  "%Temp%\*.exe" > "%Files_List2Upload%"
If Not Exist "%Files_List2Upload%" ( Goto :Error )
For /f "delims=" %%f in ('Type "%Files_List2Upload%"') Do (
    Call:Upload2VirusTotal "%%~f"
)
Taskkill /im "VirusTotalUploader2.2.exe" /f >nul 2>&1
Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Upload2VirusTotal <File>
Title "%~nx0" for Multi-files VirusTotal Uploader by Hackoo 2017
Cls
Set "File2Upload=%~1"
echo(
echo     Please wait a while ! Uploading file "%~nx1" to VirusTotal is in progress ...
Start "" "%VirusTotalUploaderTool%" "%File2Upload%"
Timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Downloading
Title Downloading VirusTotal Uploader Tool v2.2 by Hackoo 2017
Set "URL=https://www.virustotal.com/static/bin/vtuploader2.2.exe"
Rem Create "MyDownload" folder in the temporary folder
set "MyDownload_Folder=%temp%\MyDownload"
If Not Exist "%MyDownload_Folder%" MD "%MyDownload_Folder%"
Set "Setup_File=%MyDownload_Folder%\vtuploader2.2.exe"
echo(
echo       Please wait a while ! downloading "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
Rem Downloading vtuploader2.2.exe to the temporary folder
Call :Download "%URL%" "%Setup_File%"
cls
Color 9A 
Title Installing "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
echo(
echo                 Installing "vtuploader2.2.exe" is in progress ...
Rem Silent installation of vtuploader2.2.exe the uploading tool
Call :Install_Silently %Setup_File% 
Rem Removing the download folder
Call :Clean %MyDownload_Folder%
Goto Main
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Install_Silently <Setup_File>
"%~1" /S
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Clean <Folder_Setup>
RD "%~1" /S /Q >nul
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Error
cls & Color 4C
echo(
echo   The file "%Files_List2Upload%" dos not exist !
Pause>nul
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```